# Как использовать 3д модель для ragdoll unity 3d

Tags: unity3d, 3d

У меня есть 3д модель которую я сделал в blender 3d и мне нужно её использовать в unity 3d для ragdoll. Модель состоит из трех фигур это голова, левая сторона тела и правая сторона тела. Для ragdoll нужно иметь таз, голову, бедро левое, ногу левую , правое бедро, правую ногу, левый локоть, левая рука, правая рука, правый локоть и средняя кость то есть позвоночник. Для ragdoll как я знаю иметь каждую часть тела по отдельности. У меня модель состоит из трех частей левая часть тела, правая часть тела и голова. Как мне использовать её для ragdoll?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то из трех частей у Вас состоит меш, но для ragdoll'a необходимы кости

Цитата из документации.

> Ragdoll’ы используют меши с привязкой к костям (Skinned Meshes), то есть меш >персонажа, оснащённый костями в пакете 3D моделирования.

Попробуйте на mixamo создать анимацию вашему персонажу, там создадутся все кости и уже с их помощью используйте ragdoll